# Run some method at start of banch of methods (python)

Tags: python, design-patterns, methods

May be I'm doing wrong way, so tell me how to do it better.
I'm implementing one class for all instances of some object, say users. (looks like it is pattern 'Table Module' in M. Fowler's "Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture"). I attached the simplified example of my implementation.

`user` argument may be of different kinds:

- just int ID
- dictionary with information about user. it has key `id` among other
- tuple or list with ID as element with index 0

I want to determine right type of input variable `user` and get ID from it. At the same time I'd like to check if the input is correct at all. 
I'm confused about calling `__get_id` at the beginning of all methods handling user information.
I sure python can propose better and lighter solution of this problem. Or maybe the whole approach is wrong and I should implement another one.

Thanks in advance.

```
class BadInputError (Exception):
    pass

class Users:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def __is_wrong_id(self, id):
        # code to check if `id` is wrong
        return False

    def __get_id(self, user):
        if isinstance(user, int):
            ID = user
        elif isinstance(user, tuple) or isinstance(user, list):
            ID = user[0]
        elif isinstance(user, dict) and user.has_key('id'):
            ID = user['id']
        else:
            raise BadInputError
        if self.__is_wrong_id(ID):
            raise BadInputError
        return ID

    def check_user(self, user):
        uID = self.__get_id(user)
        # ...

    def delete_user(self, user):
        uID = self.__get_id(user)
        # ... 

    def assign_new_role_to(self, user):
        uID = self.__get_id(user)
        # ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here `__get_id(self, user)` make an attempt that would seem as overloading, however you're right - it's generally considered bad practice to check if a variable is an instance of a given class. In your definition you would only ever extract the first element of the tuple or list and hope that it corresponds to the ID.

Instead, you should strive to create wrappers of User that support the `__get_id()` method.

Comment: So expecting different inputs is wrong? I should use unified format of argument when calling methods, i.e. i should stop to expect `user` to be int or dict or list or tuple? And please explain more about wrappers, i don't quite understand this concept. Or better suggest a good read about it. `upd` Or I better google myself=)

Comment: Expecting different input interfaces is not a nice habit - you should create specialised functions to handle different types, which in turn call __get_id(user) to extract it out of the User object.

A wrapper is simply a class that takes an object, and either extends it by composition or provides some interface you would expect.

Python has some nice syntax for function wrappers - check out http://simeonfranklin.com/blog/2012/jul/1/python-decorators-in-12-steps/

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell with this stripped down code, but the problem that I see here is none of the methods actually use self (other than to call `___get_id` -- which doesn't use `self`).

Normally a class stores *data* and *associated methods* -- If you just have methods, then it should be a module.

Here, it makes sense for a "User" to know it's ID, so it might be worth creating a "User" class which uses the `__get_id` function to store an attribute (`self.id`). Then the `Users` class (which represents a collection of `User`s) could just check `user.id`.  e.g.:

```
class User(object):
    def __init__(self, initialize_data):
        self.__set_id(intialize_data)

    def __set_id(self, data):
        if isinstance(user, int):
            self.id = user
        elif isinstance(user, (tuple, list)):
            self.id = user[0]
        elif isinstance(user, dict) and user.has_key('id'):
            self.id = user['id']
        else:
            raise BadInputError

class Users(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.users = []

    def delete_user(self, user):
        self.users = [u for u in self.users if u.id != user.id]
```

Note that this example implementation is nowhere near optimal -- It was meant to show how I would structure the code.  A bunch of improvements could probably be made to make it more efficient (i.e., maybe a `User` could be hashible based on the `id` in which case `Users.users` could be a `set`).